# Link QGIS attribute table with Web Image?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have some layers, and I would like to link the field photograph from the attributes table to an image (Web URL).

How can I do that?  [Qgis 2.18 - Windows 10]

[image]

[image]

Something like...

[image]

I finally found the answer

[image]

Comment: You mean so each attribute has a different URL? Is there any pattern to the URLs? Is your problem that you can't edit the table? What have you tried?

Comment: No, not each attribute but each row.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, not as an edit to the question

Comment: I tried, but it doesn´t accept. Thank´s

Comment: @Paulo Martinho Did you solve it? I want to add an online picture from Google Drive to my qgis2web page. Which Qgis version did you use? Qgis 2.18?

Comment: @Paulus - Yes i solved it. Just follow the Steps in "I finally found the answer" above. [Qgis 2.18 - Windows 10]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - Create the attribute for the pictures (E.g. **PICTURES** Text(100)).

2 - Go to **Fields** in the proprieties of the layer and change the **Edit widget** (From *Text edit* to *Web view*).

[image]

[image]

3 - Now go to **attribute tables**. Put the layer in **edit** mode and insert the link or URL (for each row). Save it...

[image]

4 - Use the **Identify Features** and click above the feature.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure wether you should use "web view" or "photo" as field type.
In any case the URL should be indicated for each feature in your "Foto" field. You could also add a main one as the "Default value" (rather than constraint) in the "web view" or "photo" window.
Cheers,