# Hyperlinking images to geotagged photos in QGIS

Tags: qgis, hyperlink, photos, geotag

How can I set up a geotagged photo on QGIS 3.4 to display the image? Currently it is just a geotagged point on the map without showing the photo.

Comment: Use an "attachment" type field edit widget, as explained [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/270343/81764) (but choose "attachment" instead of "web view"). More details about field edit widgets can be found in the QGIS manual [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#edit-widgets).

Answer (score 5):

#### Preparation

When you click on a feature, using the Identify Features tool (Crtl+Shift+I), on the Identify Results panel, you can enable "Auto open form."

If you do that, when you click on a feature, you will see the feature's attributes as text strings, like:

[image: default feature attribute form]

#### Show picture

If you have the picture's path as the value of an attribute, like `filepath` in the previous image, you can customize the form to show the photograph.

Layer properties → Attributes Form

To show the picture, instead of its file path, you have to go to Layer properties and selected the Attributes Form tab.

Select the field where you have the path stored (`filepath` was used on the example).

Change two settings:
* Select Attachment as the Widget Type
* Select Image for the Integrated Document Viewer Type

The minimal settings are on the screen shot below.

[image: field settings]

Afterwards, when you click on a feature, the form will open automatically and the form contains the image. Below is the resulting form:

[image: feature attributes form with integrated image]

There are more settings you can customize. Try them.

### Alternative way to show the images

You can also use **Actions** to show the image.

You need to go to the Layer properties and selected the Actions tab.

Create an action, like in the screen shot below:

[image]

Make sure you use the field containing the path on your Action Text, like `[%filepath%]`. There is a combobox where you can choose your field name and then insert it.

If you define such action, afterwards you can select the Action and then click on a feature. The image open automatically.

[image]

The image is displayed with the default image viewer.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use the ‘ImportPhotos’ plugin.

Go to Plugins-> Manage and Install Plugins-> (select ‘all’ on the left) and search for ‘ImportPhotos’-> Install plugin

[image]

You will see a new toolbar. [image]

Click on the first icon from the left to import the geotagged photos. Then, on the pop-up window, (1) select the input folder location where all photos are saved, and (2) select the output file and its format (I selected .shp). -> Ok.
[image]

A pop-up will window will show up with the details of your import. Press the second icon on the toolbar (from left to right) and then you may click on the photo points (on canvas) to view them. On the attribute table, you may examine the characteristics of each photo.
[image]

Note: You may add one basemap to the project using this question [Adding Basemaps from Google or Bing in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20191/adding-basemaps-from-google-or-bing-in-qgis)